# SuiteCRM: How do i add JS to my custom Field

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

So I have a custom field which is basically a Bool field that hides and shows a dropdown. This is not just one custom field. I made a Field Type like Dynamicenum or Address so i can manage it via Studio. Until now i had my js code (to hide and show) inside the `EditView.tpl`.

What is the right way to add JS code to my field?

Thanks in advance

Velrest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A.** if you want to apply it on field whenever it get added to any view of any module then add your JS file in field definition. Path will be like this: *custom/include/SugarFields/Fields//EditView.tpl* and code will be like following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src='{sugar_getjspath file="custom/include/SugarFields/Fields/<your_field_type>/js_file_name.js"}'>
 </script>
```

**B.** if you want to apply js code in any specific module in specific view then use following sample method:

1. Add a reference to the javascript file which will be needed for event binding.

   **Path:**  *custom/modules/Contacts/metadata/editviewdefs.php*

**Code:**

```
<?php

$viewdefs['Contact']['EditView']['templateMeta']['includes'] =
    array (
        array (
        'file' => 'custom/modules/Contacts/js/editview.js',
        ),
    );
?>
```

2. Add the javascript file you want to include into the location you referenced above(custom/modules/Contacts/js/editview.js).
3. Quick Repair, then hard refresh your browser. All Done !

Comment: Where would i put the js file in A? As far as i know SuiteCRM compiles JS code somewhere.

Comment: normally this JS file remain in same folder (or inside js/javascript folder) with tpl file but you can keep file at any location and add proper path in tpl.

Comment: if you are talking about JS Grouping then that is something else. I think no need to add a file in SuiteCRM js grouping for this.

Comment: how are you supposed to control the order the js is executed in?  i want to overwrite functions but this method has the custom js run before the non-custom js